# Does this code have a mistake?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I am just reading about syntax of Erlang, and read this implementation of while loop:

```
-module(helloworld). 
-export([while/1,while/2, start/0]). 

while(L) -> while(L,0). 
while([], Acc) -> Acc;

while([_|T], Acc) ->
   io:fwrite("~w~n",[Acc]), 
   while(T,Acc+1). 

   start() -> 
   X = [1,2,3,4], 
   while(X).
```

Is the semicolon a mistake? (4th line: `while([], Acc) -> Acc;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the two functions like this:

```
while(L) -> while(L,0). 

while([], Acc) -> Acc;
while([_|T], Acc) ->
   io:fwrite("~w~n",[Acc]), 
   while(T,Acc+1). 

   start() -> 
   X = [1,2,3,4], 
   while(X).
```

Using whitespace to separate the function definitions makes it clear that two different functions are being defined: while/1 and while/2.

> I had no idea about `[_|T]`. It just comes after this part in the
>   tutorial, so that's very confusing.

That's nearly equivalent to `[H|T]`, which deconstructs a list into the Head and the Tail, where the Head is the first element of a list and the Tail is the rest of the list.  The variable name `_` means that you *don't care* about the variable, so you will not use it in the function body.  In this case, it means that you don't care about the Head of the list, all you want is the Tail of the list.  If a named variable is used in the head of a function clause, and you don't use the variable in the body of the function, then the compiler will give you a warning.

Here's an example of how deconstructing a list with pattern matching works:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

f([Head|Tail]) -> 
    io:format("The head of the list is: ~w~n", [Head]),
    io:format("The tail of the list is: ~w~n", [Tail]).
```

In the shell:

```
8> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

9> my:f([1, 2, 3]).
The head of the list is: 1
The tail of the list is: [2,3]
ok

10>
```

Comment: A beginners question, what does c(my) means?

Comment: @pileup, You start an *erlang shell* using the `erl` command in a terminal window.  You have to install erlang on your computer for the `erl` command to work.  Once the shell launches, you can compile your erlang program, which in my example is in a file named my.erl.  You have to compile your erlang program before you can call the functions defined in the program.  The erlang shell command `c(my)` compiles my.erl into a file named my.beam.  Once you compile the program, then you can use the shell to call the functions defined in the program, e.g. `my:f([1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are two functions defined here: `while/1` (one argument) and `while/2` (two arguments). The second one have two function bodies; which one to use is decided through pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized there is a section in the tutorial called "Pattern Matching", which also explains the syntax I had no idea about `[_|T]`. It just comes after this part in the tutorial, so that's very confusing, hopefully it will be clear after I get to that section